# How to a grab an array from a text file with array written in it?

Tags: python, arrays, text

Here is my code bellow. I am trying to create a text file that allows you to edit the keywords used in the program.

```
words = ['bob', 'jones', 'billy', 'josh']

try:
    with open('./keywords.txt', "x", encoding="utf-8") as g:
        g.write(str(words) + '\n\n' + 'EDIT THE KEYWORDS BY ADDING OR REMOVING THE TEXT\n' + 'Make sure to add use the current format in order for it to work')
except FileExistsError:
    print('Reading keywords')
    keywords = open('./keywords.txt' , "r", encoding="utf-8")
    words = keywords.readline(1)
    print(words)
```

when I use this code, all that comes out is -

> [

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This is what your text file looks like after running the program the first time:

```
['bob', 'jones', 'billy', 'josh']

EDIT THE KEYWORDS BY ADDING OR REMOVING THE TEXT
Make sure to add use the current format in order for it to work
```

Using `words = keywords.readline(1)` only reads in 1 byte of data from the line. You can use either of the following lines to return the full line:

```
keywords.readline()
keywords.readline(-1)
```

Full code:

```
words = ['bob', 'jones', 'billy', 'josh']

try:
    with open('./keywords.txt', "x", encoding="utf-8") as g:
        g.write(str(words) + '\n\n' + 'EDIT THE KEYWORDS BY ADDING OR REMOVING THE TEXT\n' + 'Make sure to add use the current format in order for it to work')
except FileExistsError:
    print('Reading keywords')
    with open('./keywords.txt' , "r", encoding="utf-8") as myFile:
        file = []
        for line in myFile:
            file.append(line)
        words = file[0]
        print(words)
```

Output:

```
Reading keywords
['bob', 'jones', 'billy', 'josh']

>>>
```

Comment: That kind of works, if I do that, then it doesn't put it into array form, but it prints it out as separate letters like "b" "i", when I would like it to be "billy" since it is for keywords.

Comment: Is that the entirety of your program? @NoobierNoob I edited my answer to reflect the entirety of what I used and show the output.

Comment: It still seems to put them as individuals.
`1 ' https://....com
1 b https://....com
1 o https://....com
1 b https://....com
1 ' https://....com
1 , https://....com
1   https://....com
1 ' https://....com
1 j https://....com`
Where is says "b" or "o", I want it to say the whole word

Comment: I tried making another edit to the code, this time looping through the file and storing the first line. It still gives me the correct output, I'm not sure why yours is differing. What is causing the URL format in your output? I'm wondering if the error is in a different section of the program. It almost seems like somewhere you are looping through the list and only grabbing the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()` . Replace `readline(1)` with `readline()`. Here is the code.

```
words = ['bob', 'jones', 'billy', 'josh']
import ast
try:
    with open('./keywords.txt', "x", encoding="utf-8") as g:
        g.write(str(words) + '\n\n' + 'EDIT THE KEYWORDS BY ADDING OR REMOVING THE TEXT\n' + 'Make sure to add use the current format in order for it to work')
except FileExistsError:
    print('Reading keywords')
    keywords = open('./keywords.txt' , "r", encoding="utf-8")
    words = keywords.readline()
    listobj = ast.literal_eval(words)
    print(listobj)
    print(listobj[2])
```

prints

```
['bob', 'jones', 'billy', 'josh']
billy
```

Comment: has the same issue where it splits up the words into letters as the other answer.

Comment: Every word is composed of letters, so it will split it up into letters. What do you exactly want? In this code, all words are stored in a list